# php mysql bind_param inserting single row only

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone explain why below code inserting single row in mysql database only.
i check array with echo function it returning two rows.

```
$counter=1; // just assume
$orderid=date("mY").'-'.str_pad($counter, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
 $stmt = $stmt_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO tblorder_detail(orderid,idno,productid,side,quantity,price,design,days,uploadtime,deliverytime,filecheck,isdelete) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$i=0;
foreach ($saved_cart_items as $key => $value) { 
$i++;
$isdelete=0;   

$stmt->bind_param("siiiidiissii", $orderid, $i, $value['productid'], $value['side'], $value['quantity'], $value['price'], $value['design'], $value['days'], $value['uploadtime'], $value['deliveryid'], $value['filecheck'], $isdelete  );
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Make the primary id of the table null after each iteration of the for loop

Comment: declare the `$i=1;`  in outside the `foreach`

Comment: sorry for incomplete code, i already declared $i=0; before forreach. it inserting single row only even though i check array by echo, its returning 2 rows

Comment: What is the primary key for your table

Comment: orderid is primary key, $orderid=date("mY").'-'.str_pad($counter, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

Comment: check my answer @MaleBkk

Comment: thanks @ AAT and @JYoThI the problem was primary key, i made it composite key ( orderid+idno) .problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** you need to declare the `$i=1;` in outside the `foreach` . otherwise in the first time `$i` is undefined . so it's throwing error . In next loop it will become `1` so it's inserting second row only .

**2nd :** you can bind the variable like below

```
$stmt = $stmt_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO tblorder_detail(orderid,idno,productid,side,quantity,price,design,days,uploadtime,deliverytime,filecheck,isdelete) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("siiiidiissii", $orderid, $i, $productid, $side, $quantity, $price, $design, $days, $uploadtime, $deliveryid, $filecheck, $isdelete  );
$i=1;
foreach ($saved_cart_items as $key => $value) { 
$i++;
$isdelete=0;   
$productid = $value['productid'];
$side=$value['side'];
$value['quantity'];
$price= $value['price'];
$design= $value['design'];
$days= $value['days'];
$uploadtime=$value['uploadtime'];
$deliveryid=$value['deliveryid'];
$filecheck=$value['filecheck'];


$stmt->execute();
}
```